# python-ldap3 is unable to add user to and existing LDAP group

Tags: python, active-directory, openldap, python-ldap, ldap3

I am able successfully connect using LDAP3 and retrieve my LDAP group members as below.

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, SUBTREE
from ldap3.extend.microsoft.addMembersToGroups import ad_add_members_to_groups as addMembersToGroups

>>> conn = Connection(Server('ldaps://ldap.****.com:***', get_info=ALL),check_names=False, auto_bind=False,user="ANT\*****",password="******", authentication="NTLM")
>>> 
>>> conn.open()
>>> conn.search('ou=Groups,o=****.com', '(&(cn=MY-LDAP-GROUP))', attributes=['cn', 'objectclass', 'memberuid'])
it returns True and I can see members by printing 
conn.entries
>>>
```

The above line says `MY-LDAP-GROUP` exists and returns `TRUE` while searching but throws **LDAP group not found** when I try to an user to the group as below

```
>>> addMembersToGroups(conn, ['myuser'], 'MY-LDAP-GROUP')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/****/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ldap3/extend/microsoft/addMembersToGroups.py", line 69, in ad_add_members_to_groups
    raise LDAPInvalidDnError(group + ' not found')
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPInvalidDnError: MY-LDAP-GROUP not found
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

After so many trial and errors, I got frustrated and used the older `python-ldap` library to add existing users. Now my code is a mixture of `ldap3` and `ldap`.

I know this is not what the OP has desired. But this may help someone.

Here the user Dinesh Kumar is already part of a group group1. I am trying to add him
to another group group2 which is successful and does not disturb the existing group

```
import ldap
import ldap.modlist as modlist

def add_existing_user_to_group(user_name, user_id, group_id):
    """
    :return:
    """

    # ldap expects a byte string.
    converted_user_name = bytes(user_name, 'utf-8')
    converted_user_id = bytes(user_id, 'utf-8')
    converted_group_id = bytes(group_id, 'utf-8')

    # Add all the attributes for the new dn
    ldap_attr = {}
    ldap_attr['uid'] = converted_user_name
    ldap_attr['cn'] = converted_user_name
    ldap_attr['uidNumber'] = converted_user_id
    ldap_attr['gidNumber'] = converted_group_id
    ldap_attr['objectClass'] =  [b'top', b'posixAccount', b'inetOrgPerson']
    ldap_attr['sn'] = b'Kumar'
    ldap_attr['homeDirectory'] = b'/home/users/dkumar'

    # Establish connection to server using ldap
    conn = ldap.initialize(server_uri, bytes_mode=False)
    bind_resp = conn.simple_bind_s("cn=admin,dc=testldap,dc=com", "password")

    dn_new = "cn={},cn={},ou=MyOU,dc=testldap,dc=com".format('Dinesh Kumar','group2')

    ldif = modlist.addModlist(ldap_attr)
    try:
        response = conn.add_s(dn_new, ldif)
    except ldap.error as e:
        response = e
    print(" The response is ", response)
    conn.unbind()
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

> The above line says `MY-LDAP-GROUP` exists and returns `TRUE`

Returning `True` just means that the search succeeded. It doesn't mean that anything was found. Is there anything in `conn.entries`?

But I suspect your real problem is something different. If [this](https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3/blob/master/ldap3/extend/microsoft/addMembersToGroups.py) is the source code for `ad_add_members_to_groups`, then it is expecting the `distinguishedName` of the group (notice the parameter name `group_dn`), but you're passing the `cn` (common name). For example, your code should be something like:

```
addMembersToGroups(conn, ['myuser'], 'CN=MY-LDAP-GROUP,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com')
```

If you don't know the DN, then ask for the `distinguishedName` attribute from the search.

A word of warning: that code for `ad_add_members_to_groups` retrieves all the current members before adding the new member. You might run into performance problems if you're working with groups that have large membership because of that (e.g. if the group has 1000 members, it will load all 1000 before adding anyone). You don't actually need to do that (you *can* add a new member without looking at the current membership). I think what they're trying to avoid is the error you get when you try to add someone who is already in the group. But I think there are better ways to handle that. It might not matter to you if you're only working with small groups.

Comment: yes i see entries. ``conn.entries`` sorry forget to mention

Comment: Good. Did you try to pass the DN to `addMembersToGroups` like I described?

Comment: @GabrielLuci I tried giving a dn for both `members_dn` and `groups_dn`. It throws the following error . `ErrorResult - [('result', 65), ('description', 'objectClassViolation'), ('dn', ''), ('message', "attribute 'member' not allowed")]`

Comment: @DineshKumar It sounds like it's trying to set the `member` attribute on a user. Did you accidentally reverse the `members_dn` and `groups_dn`? The order of the parameters should be `connection`, `members_dn`, `groups_dn`.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I believe I have given the right params. Do you mind giving an example with the right syntax? Your example in the above answer does not show dn for member attribute.